# How to implement oAuth in Django with Tastipie

Tags: django, oauth, tastypie

How to implement oAuth in django with Tastipie API framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tastypie allows you to use OAuthAuthentication class for your authentication.

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
class Meta:
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    authentication = OAuthAuthentication()
```

With this method your resource will expect to receive access token. 
You need [django-oauth-plus](http://code.larlet.fr/django-oauth-plus/wiki/Home), which gives you full functionality to get user access token.