# tastypie + angularjs + phonegap

Tags: django, angularjs, rest, cordova, tastypie

First of all, Happy New Year to all the craftsmen, hackers, programmers, electronic wizards etc !
I have a question in regard to authentication & authorization of a web mobile app(angularjs + phonegap) & a backend service(rest - django/tastypie). How can I create or authorize a user(using facebook, twitter) with/in the django/tastypie backend ?

Any ideas?
I read all other post in regard to this "issue", but I could not find a proper way to do this. Any suggestions, help, advice would be welcomed !

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) in your system. Two way you can have this

To implement with `Django and Tasty` try this

- [Building a True OAuth 2.0 API with Django and Tasty Pie](http://ianalexandr.com/blog/building-a-true-oauth-20-api-with-django-and-tasty-pie.html)
- [Simple OAuth 2.0 authentication model for django-tastypie.](https://github.com/ianalexander/django-oauth2-tastypie)
- And this answer [How to implement oAuth in Django with Tastipie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274738/how-to-implement-oauth-in-django-with-tastipie)

Or to implement with `JavaScript` try this

- This answer [AngularJS + OAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18218293/angularjs-oauth)
- Here is an [angularjs example](https://github.com/enginous/angular-oauth)
- This answer [How do I implement secure OAuth2 consumption in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440398/how-do-i-implement-secure-oauth2-consumption-in-javascript)
- [New JavaScript SDK & OAuth 2.0 based FBConnect Tutorial](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/new-javascript-sdk-oauth-2-0-based-fbconnect-tutorial/)

I would go with `Django and Tasty`.

Comment: Ok, I've implemented OAuth2. How can I use facebook connect ?

Comment: A little bit more details, please !

Comment: I don't know exactly, how can I achieve the following:
I open the mobile app(phonegap), login in with facebook, and after this step, I want an account to be created on the server(django + tastypie) with the fb data of that user. If that user already has an account, then it's ok, move further in the mobile app.
Thank you very much !